# How to start a new activity on android client when receive a message from server

Tags: java, android, client-server

I have problem with starting a new activity in android. I have looked through many other questions here, but I didn't find an answer. Here's the problem:
Four classes:
1. WelcomeActivity;
2. MainActivity;
3. PopUpActivity;
4. Client;

At the begining starts WelcomeActivity where you you type all needed credentials to connect to the server, after you clicked the button, string is sent to server. Server send validation string if everything is OK. If OK is received, then MainActivity is started. Users types different things in MainActivity, the presses another button, which send another string to the server. Server processes it (string) and send back a response, also a string. And here's the problem. When server send that last string to client I want to start PopUpActivity, where will be displayed this aprticualr string in TextView.

My code:
Client part (last else if):

```
   public void run() throws Exception {
        Socket client = new Socket(ip, port);
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
    out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
    out.println(welcomeActivity.getCredentials());
    while (true) {
        final String line = in.readLine();
        if (line.equals("#GO#")) {
            System.out.println("#GO#");
            mainActivityIntent = new Intent(welcomeActivity,
                    MainActivity.class);
            welcomeActivity.startActivity(mainActivityIntent);
        } else if (line.equals("#CLOSE#")) {
            client.close();
            break;
        } else if (line.startsWith("#RESULTS")) {           
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.getContext(), PopUpActivity.class);
            i.putExtra(line, line);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            MainActivity.getContext().startActivity(i);             
        }
    }
}
```

WelcomeActivity:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    ip = ipText.getText().toString();
    port = Integer.parseInt(portText.getText().toString());
    login = loginText.getText().toString();
    password = passwordText.getText().toString();
    credentials = login + "#" + password + "#" + brand + "#" + device + "#"
            + hardware + "#" + manufacturer + "#" + product;
    client = new Client(ip, port, this);
    new Handler().start();
}

private class Handler extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        try {
            client.run();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

PopUpActivity:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pop_up);
    closeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.closeButton);
    testOutcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textArea);
    closeButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    //
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras == null) {
        return;
    }
    String value = extras.getString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
    if (value != null) {
        testOutcome.setText(value);
    }
}
```

PopUpActivity is started, but text is not displayed.

Before that I tried to use Context in MainActivity:

```
final static Context context;
 ....
public void onCreate() {
context = getBaseContext();
// or context = getApplicationContext();
....
 }
 ...
 public static Context getContext() {
  return context;
 }
```

And from clint tried to call:

```
 MainActivity.getContext().getTextView().setText(line);
```

At the begining I tied to call a AlertDialog, but it also was bad, NullPointerException

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your intent calling, so you may write 
    `i.putExtra("line",line);` in your MainActivity
and you can retrieve it by 
    `Intent intent = getIntent(); intent.getStringExtra("line");` in your PopUp Activity.